# API only rendering after I start typing (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a small twitter-like app with React and Firebase, and am encountering a small bug. Right now, I am using UseEffect to display my firebase collection on page load, and then mapping the tweets to the page. However, the tweets only show up after I start typing.
Here is how I'm making the call.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        let newArray = []
        const getTweets = async () => {
            firebase.firestore().collection('tweet').orderBy('date',
         'desc').onSnapshot((singleTweet) => {
                singleTweet.forEach((element) => {
                    newArray.push(element.data())
                })
            })
            showLoader()            
            setTweets(newArray)
            if (newArray) {
                hideLoader()
            }
        }
        getTweets();
    }, [])

const addTweet = (text) => {
    const newTweets = {}
    newTweets.content = text;
    newTweets.date = new Date().toISOString()
    newTweets.userName = user.displayName
    newTweets.photoURL = user.photoURL
    setTweets([newTweets, ...tweetList])
    firebase.firestore().collection('tweet').add(newTweets)

}
const submitTweetHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    addTweet(inputText)
    setInputText('')
}
```

And this is where I'm mapping the collection:

```js
{tweetList.map((tweet, index) => (<Tweet key={index} tweet={tweet} />))}
```

Comment: Did you try move `setTweets(newArray)` after `singleTweet` forEach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the functionality you might want to switch to `.get`

But since this should be async like @Nooruddin suggested, you need to have a `.then` in order to use the snapshot of your collection

Try:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getTweets = async() => {
    let newArray = []
    await firebase.firestore().collection('tweet').orderBy('date', 'desc').get()
      .then(((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((singleTweet) => {
          newArray.push(singleTweet.data())
        })
      }))
    showLoader()
    setTweets(newArray)
    if (newArray) {
      hideLoader()
    }
  }
  getTweets();
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `await` in async like

```
useEffect(() => {
        ...
        const getTweets = async () => {
            await firebase.firestore().collection('tweet').orderBy('date',
         'desc').onSnapshot((singleTweet) => {
                ....
            })
            ...
        }
        ...
    }, [])
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! It's still the same :/ not loading before

Comment: Try console log before `setTweets(newArray)` and check whats data in `newArray`

Comment: It has an array of objects with all the tweets of the data base of firebase

Comment: onSnapshot doesn't return a promise, so you can't await its results.  It adds a persistent listener.